# How to have string query and date query at the same time in Laravel with Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-9

At first my code works fine with just one parameter when querying, but when I add more parameters, it start to throw errors.

Here is `MyEditController` file:

```
class AdminEditController extends Controller
{
//edit didalam lihat_datafile
public function edit(Request $request,$id){
 $data = lokasipekerjaan::find($id);
$data->mid=$request->mid;
$data->subid=$request->subid;
$data->pekerjaan=$request->pekerjaan;
$data->lokasi=$request->lokasi;
$data->uom=$request->uom;
$data->cut=$request->cut;
$data->fill=$request->fill;
$data->area=$request->area;
$data->tanggal=$request->tanggal;

$data->save();
return redirect()->back();

}
```

Here is my `web.php` :

```
Route::resource('lokasipekerjaan', AdminEditController::class);
```

Here is my Blade:

```
 @foreach($data as $datas)
                        <form action="{{route('lokasipekerjaan.edit',[$datas->id])}}" method="PUT">
                      <tr class="table-info">
                        <td> <input  type="text" value="{{ $datas->id }}" class="" style="background-color: #E0FFFF;width:40px;height:40px;" name="id" :value="old('id')"> </input> </td>
                        <td><input id="{{ $datas->mid }}" type="text" value="{{ $datas->mid }}" class="" style="background-color:   #E0FFFF;width:40px;height:40px;" name="mid" :value="old('mid')"></td>
                        <td> <input id="{{ $datas->subid }}" type="text" value="{{ $datas->subid }} " class="" style="background-color: #E0FFFF;width:100px;height:40px;" name="subid" :value="old('subid')"> </td>
                        <td> <input id="{{ $datas->pekerjaan }}" type="text" value="{{ $datas->pekerjaan }} "class="" style="background-color:  #E0FFFF;height:40px;" name="pekerjaan" :value="old('pekerjaan')"> </td>
                        <td> <input id="{{ $datas->lokasi }}" type="text" value="{{ $datas->lokasi }} " class="" style="background-color:   #E0FFFF;height:40px;" name="lokasi" :value="old('lokasi')"> </td>
                        <td> <input id="{{ $datas->cut }}" type="text" value="{{ $datas->cut }} " class="" style="background-color: #E0FFFF;height:40px;" name="volume" :value="old('cut')"> </td>
                        <td> <input id="{{ $datas->fill }}" type="text" value="{{ $datas->fill }} " class="" style="background-color:   #E0FFFF;height:40px;" name="volume" :value="old('fill')"> </td>
                        <td> <input id="{{ $datas->area }}" type="text" value="{{ $datas->area }} " class="" style="background-color:   #E0FFFF;height:40px;" name="volume" :value="old('area')"> </td>
                        <td> <input id="{{ $datas->uom }}" type="text" value="{{ $datas->uom }} " class="" style="background-color: #E0FFFF;width:40px;height:40px;" name="uom" :value="old('uom')"> </td>
                        <td>  <input value="{{ $datas->tanggal }} " type="text" value="{{ $datas->tanggal }} " class="" style="background-color:    #E0FFFF;width:100px;height:40px;" name="tanggal" :value="old('tanggal')"> </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
                            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
                            <input type="submit" onclick="return confirm('apakah anda yakin ingin mengedit data ini ?');" class="btn btn-primary" value="Edit"/>@method('PUT')
                          </form></td>
```

Here is My Controller:

```
public function lihatdata(){
        if(Auth::id()){
        $caridata = $_GET['query'];
        $tanggal_dari = $_GET['tanggaldari'];
        $tanggal_ke = $_GET['tanggalke'];
        $filtersubid = dataacuan::select('subid')->whereNotNull('subid')->distinct()->get();
        $data = lokasipekerjaan::when($caridata,function($caridatat,$caridata){
            return $caridatat->where('cut','LIKE','%'.$caridata.'%')
            ->orwhere('fill','LIKE','%'.$caridata.'%')
            ->orwhere('mid','LIKE','%'.$caridata.'%')
            ->orwhere('subid','LIKE','%'.$caridata.'%')
            ->orwhere('lokasi','LIKE','%'.$caridata.'%')
            ->orwhere('id','LIKE','%'.$caridata.'%')
            ->orwhere('pekerjaan','LIKE','%'.$caridata.'%')
            ->groupby('subid')->select(
                DB::raw("DATE(tanggal) as tanggal"),
            );
        })->whereDate('tanggal','>=',$tanggal_dari) 
        ->whereDate('tanggal','<=',$tanggal_ke)->paginate(5);
        return view('admin.lihat_data',compact('data','caridata','filtersubid','tanggal_dari','tanggal_ke'));}else{
            return view('admin.notfound');
        }
    }
```

When I adding Some Parameter using this code it start showing error:

```
->select(
            DB::raw("DATE(tanggal) as tanggal"),
        );
    })->whereDate('tanggal','>=',$tanggal_dari) 
    ->whereDate('tanggal','<=',$tanggal_ke)
```

When I filter it with date it work fine but when I start to querying with strings it showing this error below:

[image]

How Can i fix that please ?

Thank You....

Comment: The route `lokasipekerjaan/{lokasipekerjaan}/edit` is missing a required parameter lokasipekerjaan. How are you accessing it?

Comment: with Route::resource('lokasipekerjaan', AdminEditController::class); in web.php function sir and
in the blade:
{{route('lokasipekerjaan.edit',[$datas->id])}}

Comment: the edit button is working pretty well when there is not tanggaldari and tanggalke(date) parameter when querrying...

Comment: when i delete below code it work fine....
->select(
                DB::raw("DATE(tanggal) as tanggal"),
            );
        })->whereDate('tanggal','>=',$tanggal_dari) 
        ->whereDate('tanggal','<=',$tanggal_ke)

Comment: Can you check `$data->total()` to make sure you get matches? Otherwise filtering by a keyword will probably cause no matches.

Comment: @KevinY where do i need to do that ?

Comment: Ah, your `select(DB::raw("DATE(tanggal) as tanggal"),)` doesn't select the id. Try adding the id to it.

Comment: add the id ? what id ?

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: yes it worked but at the same time it's just remove all the data value,except id when i try querrying it with string

Comment: ohhh i get the answer just add more colum behind that thanks @KevinY select(
                DB::raw("DATE(tanggal) as tanggal"),'id','subid','mid'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter needs to be named:

```
{{route('lokasipekerjaan.edit',['lokasipekerjaan'=>$datas->id])}}
```

Also make sure you're getting matches.
`$datas->id` is probably null. When paginating you can check `$data->total()` if it's 0 that means there's no matches when you're filtering by a keyword.

**Edit:**
So it looks like your when logic overrides the select logic:

```
->select(
    DB::raw("DATE(tanggal) as tanggal"),
)
```

In the above, when you before were getting `*`, you now no longer get the id field. You should add the fields which you need:

```
->select(
    DB::raw("DATE(tanggal) as tanggal, id")
)
```

**Edit2:**

Regarding the outside date range, there's no parenthesis within the query that will get generated. You'd want to wrap the searching logic within parenthesis otherwise the OR's would check whichever is true, and short circuit before the date range check.

Instead of this:

```
$data = lokasipekerjaan::when($caridata,function($caridatat,$caridata){
            return $caridatat->where('cut','LIKE','%'.$caridata.'%')
            ->orwhere('fill','LIKE','%'.$caridata.'%')
            ->orwhere('mid','LIKE','%'.$caridata.'%')
            ->orwhere('subid','LIKE','%'.$caridata.'%')
            ->orwhere('lokasi','LIKE','%'.$caridata.'%')
            ->orwhere('id','LIKE','%'.$caridata.'%')
            ->orwhere('pekerjaan','LIKE','%'.$caridata.'%')
            ->groupby('subid')->select(
                DB::raw("DATE(tanggal) as tanggal"),
            );
        })->whereDate('tanggal','>=',$tanggal_dari) 
        ->whereDate('tanggal','<=',$tanggal_ke)->paginate(5);
```

Wrap the search within a where like so:

```
        $data = lokasipekerjaan::when($caridata,function($caridatat,$caridata){
            return $caridatat->where(function($caridatat) use ($caridata) {
                $caridatat->where('cut','LIKE','%'.$caridata.'%')
                ->orwhere('fill','LIKE','%'.$caridata.'%')
                ->orwhere('mid','LIKE','%'.$caridata.'%')
                ->orwhere('subid','LIKE','%'.$caridata.'%')
                ->orwhere('lokasi','LIKE','%'.$caridata.'%')
                ->orwhere('id','LIKE','%'.$caridata.'%')
                ->orwhere('pekerjaan','LIKE','%'.$caridata.'%')
                ->groupby('subid')->select(
                    DB::raw("DATE(tanggal) as tanggal"),
                );
            });
        })->whereDate('tanggal','>=',$tanggal_dari) 
        ->whereDate('tanggal','<=',$tanggal_ke)->paginate(5);
```

Comment: i already done that but it's not working...
the problem is when i add below code in querry:
>select(                 DB::raw("DATE(tanggal) as tanggal"),             );         })->whereDate('tanggal','>=',$tanggal_dari)          ->whereDate('tanggal','<=',$tanggal_ke)

Comment: when it's single parameter querry without date it just work fineee....

Comment: @MuhammadBayuKurniawan Probably null. $datas doesn't appear in your controller. Can you show what it's set to? Did you mean `$data->id`?

Comment: okay i'm gonna edit my question

Comment: yes it worked but at the same time it's just remove all the data value,except id when i try querrying it with string

Comment: ohhh i get the answer just add more colum behind that thanks @KevinY select(
                DB::raw("DATE(tanggal) as tanggal"),'id','subid','mid'

Comment: @MuhammadBayuKurniawan Add in all the columns you're using as well. I believe: mid,subid,pekerjaan,lokasi,cut,fill, area, uom

Comment: but it doesn't work really what i wanted to... it's still showing the other data outside of the date.if you know how to filter it entirely and ignore the querry behind the date parameter please ?

thank you...

Comment: @MuhammadBayuKurniawan I believe your when statement just puts a bunch of OR's without parenthesis. you can wrap it all within a where to get parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

The route lokasipekerjaan/**{path_parameter}**/edit is missing a required path parameter.
Look for code snippets like

```
route('lokasipekerjaan.edit', $params)
```

on **admin.lihat_data**

view file. the $params variable may by empty or null?

Comment: i already done that but it's not working... the problem is when i add below code in querry: >select( DB::raw("DATE(tanggal) as tanggal"), ); })->whereDate('tanggal','>=',$tanggal_dari) ->whereDate('tanggal','<=',$tanggal_ke)

Answer (score 0):

i think i get the answer this is when the code error:

```
public function lihatdata(){
    if(Auth::id()){
    $caridata = $_GET['query'];
    $tanggal_dari = $_GET['tanggaldari'];
    $tanggal_ke = $_GET['tanggalke'];
    $filtersubid = dataacuan::select('subid')->whereNotNull('subid')->distinct()->get();
    $data = lokasipekerjaan::when($caridata,function($caridatat,$caridata){
        return $caridatat->where('cut','LIKE','%'.$caridata.'%')
        ->orwhere('fill','LIKE','%'.$caridata.'%')
        ->orwhere('mid','LIKE','%'.$caridata.'%')
        ->orwhere('subid','LIKE','%'.$caridata.'%')
        ->orwhere('lokasi','LIKE','%'.$caridata.'%')
        ->orwhere('id','LIKE','%'.$caridata.'%')
        ->orwhere('pekerjaan','LIKE','%'.$caridata.'%')
        ->groupby('subid')->select(
            DB::raw("DATE(tanggal) as tanggal"),
        );
    })->whereDate('tanggal','>=',$tanggal_dari) 
    ->whereDate('tanggal','<=',$tanggal_ke)->paginate(5);
    return view('admin.lihat_data',compact('data','caridata','filtersubid','tanggal_dari','tanggal_ke'));}else{
        return view('admin.notfound');
    }
}
```

this when it work:

```
 public function lihatdata(){
    if(Auth::id()){
    $caridata = $_GET['query'];
    $tanggal_dari = $_GET['tanggaldari'];
    $tanggal_ke = $_GET['tanggalke'];
    $filtersubid = dataacuan::select('subid')->whereNotNull('subid')->distinct()->get();
    $data = lokasipekerjaan::when($caridata,function($caridatat,$caridata){
        return $caridatat->where('cut','LIKE','%'.$caridata.'%')
        ->orwhere('fill','LIKE','%'.$caridata.'%')
        ->orwhere('mid','LIKE','%'.$caridata.'%')
        ->orwhere('subid','LIKE','%'.$caridata.'%')
        ->orwhere('lokasi','LIKE','%'.$caridata.'%')
        ->orwhere('id','LIKE','%'.$caridata.'%')
        ->orwhere('pekerjaan','LIKE','%'.$caridata.'%')
        ->groupby('subid');
    })->whereDate('tanggal','>=',$tanggal_dari) 
    ->whereDate('tanggal','<=',$tanggal_ke)->paginate(5);
    return view('admin.lihat_data',compact('data','caridata','filtersubid','tanggal_dari','tanggal_ke'));}else{
        return view('admin.notfound');
    }
}
```

this is what i remove in my code :

```
->select(
        DB::raw("DATE(tanggal) as tanggal"),
    )
```

i don't know how my code is working... but if someone know the theory behind that you guys can answer it....

but it doesn't work really what i wanted to... it's still showing the other data outside of the date.if anyone know how to filter it entirely and ignore the query behind the date parameter please ?

thank you for the help guys...

Comment: Regarding the outside date range, that is due to no parentheses and short-circuiting caused by the OR's . You can wrap the entire keyword search logic within a where closure to keep the OR's restricted within parentheses. Otherwise there will be short-circuiting and the date won't be checked if a keyword match is found. See my updated answer.